# How do I setup a RAID config on an Asus M3N-HT Deluxe running already installed Windows 7 Ultimate?

Tags: windows-7, raid, bsod

The setup:

Asus M3N-HT Deluxe / 
AMD Phenom II X6 1090T / 
Windows 7 Ultimate

I have a total of 6 drives...

5 of them are identical Seagate Barracuda 3TB (2.72TB)

I have a 2TB Drive currently running my OS

I would like to purchase a 6th identical drive and setup have a RAID 10 setup...

I have attempted to setup 4 of the drives in a RAID 10 setup and everytime Windows boots. I get a BSOD...

Has anyone experienced this or attempted something similar with success?

Answer (score 0):

I have a different ASUS mobo and a different RAID controller, but I had to setup my RAID arrays and then install the OS to it. I didn't setup a RAID 10, I setup a RAID 5 for storage and a RAID 1 for OS.

This person, on-the-other-hand, seems to have been able to accomplish something similar to what you are wanting to do except just for a RAID 0. I would imagine that for a RAID 10 it would be similar. Where he sets up his RAID, you would setup your two RAID levels.

http://www.guytechie.com/articles/2011/4/13/upgrade-to-raid-without-reinstalling-windows.html